# Arrays en React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

Estoy aprendiendo React, mi proyecto es un quiz que dependiendo la temática te deje ver diferentes tipos de preguntas y hace unos días que estoy trabado con un problema que no puedo solucionar.
Primero tengo el siguiente código, donde importo el array "Questions" que es para manejar un array de preguntas:

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react'
import { Questions } from '../Helpers/QuestionBank'
import {QuizContext} from '../Helpers/Context'


export default function Quiz() {
    const [currQuestion, setCurrQuestion] = useState(0); 
    const [optionChosen, setOptionChosen] = useState ("")
    const { score, setScore, setGameState } = useContext(QuizContext)

    const nextQuestion = () => {
        if (Questions[currQuestion].answer == optionChosen){
            setScore(score + 1);
        }
        //alert(score)
        setCurrQuestion(currQuestion + 1);
    }

    const finishQuiz = () => {
        if (Questions[currQuestion].answer == optionChosen){
            setScore(score + 1);
        }

        setGameState ("endscreen")
    }

    return (
        <div className = "Quiz">
            <h1>{Questions[currQuestion].prompt}</h1> 
            <div className = "options">
                <button onClick = {() => setOptionChosen ("A")}>{Questions[currQuestion].optionA}</button>
                <button onClick = {() => setOptionChosen ("B")}>{Questions[currQuestion].optionB}</button>
                <button onClick = {() => setOptionChosen ("C")}>{Questions[currQuestion].optionC}</button>
                <button onClick = {() => setOptionChosen ("D")}>{Questions[currQuestion].optionD}</button>
            </div>
            {currQuestion == Questions.length - 1 ? (
                <button onClick = {finishQuiz}>FInish Quiz</button>
            ) : (
                <button onClick = {nextQuestion}> Next Question</button>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Anda perfecto**, el problema es que yo quiero tener en un archivo *JS* todas las preguntas con diferentes arrays (dependiendo la temática) y guardar en un array vacío que se llame Questions al seleccionar la temática correspondiente. Lo que no puedo resolver es como guardar dependiendo de la temática para que lo termine exportando.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import {useState} from 'react'
import {QuizContext} from '../Helpers/Context'


export const Questions = [ 
        {prompt: "1+2?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2",answer: "D"},
            
        {prompt: "2+2?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2", answer: "C"},
     
        {prompt: "12+12?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2", answer: "A",}
        ]


  export default function QuestionBank () {
 
    const { gameTheme, setGameState} = useContext(QuizContext);
    const [ Preguntas, setQuestions] = useState ([]);
    const Questions = []; 

        const Arte = [
            {prompt: "1+2?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2",answer: "D"},
                
            {prompt: "2+2?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2", answer: "C"},
         
            {prompt: "12+12?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2", answer: "A",}]
        
        const Ciencia = [
            {prompt: "1+1?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2",answer: "D"},
                
            {prompt: "2+2?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2", answer: "C"},
         
            {prompt: "12+12?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2", answer: "A",}]
        
        const Deportes = [
            {prompt: "1+1?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2",answer: "D"},
                
            {prompt: "2+2?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2", answer: "C"},
         
            {prompt: "12+12?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2", answer: "A",}]
        
        const Entretenimiento = [
                {prompt: "1+1?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2",answer: "D"},
                    
                {prompt: "2+2?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2", answer: "C"},
            
                {prompt: "12+12?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2", answer: "A",}] 

        const Geografía = [
            {prompt: "1+1?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2",answer: "D"},
                
            {prompt: "2+2?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2", answer: "C"},
         
            {prompt: "12+12?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2", answer: "A",}]

        const Historia = [
            {prompt: "1+1?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2",answer: "D"},
                
            {prompt: "2+2?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2", answer: "C"},
         
            {prompt: "12+12?", optionA: "24", optionB: "21", optionC: "4", optionD: "2", answer: "A",}]
        
        

    return (
        <div>
            {gameTheme === "Arte" && Question } 
            {gameTheme === "Ciencia" && setQuestions(Ciencia)}
            {gameTheme === "Deportes" && setQuestions(Deportes)}
            {gameTheme === "Entretenimiento" && setQuestions(Entretenimiento)}
            {gameTheme === "Geografía" && setQuestions(Geografía)}
            {gameTheme === "Historia" && setQuestions(Historia)} 
        </div>    
    );  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una manera de lograrlo podría ser usando el hook UseEffect. Primero mueves la variable *[questions, setQuestions]* al *QuizContext*, luego en *QuestionBank* al seleccionar la temática en *gameTheme* de alguna manera(por ejemplo al hacer click), se activaría el useEffect que actualice la constante *questions* , algo así:

```
useEffect(() => {
    gameTheme === "Arte" && setQuestions(Arte)
    gameTheme === "Ciencia" && setQuestions(Ciencia)
    gameTheme === "Deportes" && setQuestions(Deportes)
    gameTheme === "Entretenimiento" && setQuestions(Entretenimiento)
    gameTheme === "Geografía" && setQuestions(Geografía)
    gameTheme === "Historia" && setQuestions(Historia)

},[gameTheme])
```

Luego puedes mostrar las preguntas directamente en el componente Quiz usando el contexto.